# Would rebinding be objectionable?

Tags: clojure

Given is this s-exp:

```
(let [temp 30
      temp (* temp 9/5)
      temp (+ temp 32)]
  temp)
```

Ignoring the fact that the arithmetic could be inlined, would rebinding `temp` like this be objectionable in Clojure? Why/Why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is used in core.clj in the definition of the conditional threading macros for an example. If splitting the construction of a value into segments makes it clear for human consumption then I would confidently say that this is a fine use of this pattern.

It's worth noting that many Clojurians will interpret the word 'rebinding' to mean using the `bind` function. You are using it accurately, though it has another meaning as well.

Answer (score 3):

That's not very functional--in a `let` every variable should mean something. I would refactor it to this:

```
(let [celsius 30
      fahrenheit-unnormalized (* celsius 9/5)
      fahrenheit (+ fahrenheit 32)
  fahrenheit)
```

(I'm ignoring the better solution:)

```
(+ (* temp 9/5) 32)
```

Answer (score 2):

Re-binding within `let` can often be expressed with one of the threading macros. The following expression is equivalent to the expression from the question:

```
 (-> 30 (* 9/5) (+ 32))
```

This particular expression can obviously be simplified even further but often `->` or `->>` strike the good spot between unreadability due to reuse of symbols (rebinding) and unreadability due to nesting (which happens if you replace the rebinding with a huge nested expression.)

Comment: I am aware of the threading macro's, in fact there is a [nice library](https://github.com/rplevy/swiss-arrows) that takes the idea a step further.
I asked the question because I wondered whether rebinding a let-local binding could introduce any (maybe subtle) bugs, or whether I could freely choose among these 2 options. Sometimes I find the let-form just plain nicer to read TBH.